# Mozenda Bulk Insertion with Python Script

Tags: python, api, bulk, insertion

I'm trying to write a python script to perform a bulk insertion over the Mozenda API.  They give an example in C# in the documentation.  https://mozenda.com/api#h9

test.xml - example below.

```
<ItemList>
  <Item>
    <First>32</First>
    <Second>03</Second>
    <Third>403</Third>
    <Fourth>015</Fourth>
    <Fifth>0000</Fifth>
    <PIN>32034030150000</PIN>
  </Item>
</ItemList>
```

My Code:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = 'https://api.mozenda.com/rest?WebServiceKey=[CANNOT-PROVIDE]&Service=Mozenda10&Operation=Collection.AddItem&CollectionID=1037'

fileName = '/Users/me/Desktop/test.xml'

req = urllib2.Request(url, fileName)
moz_response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

response_data = moz_response.read()

print response_data
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CollectionAddItemResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Result>Success</Result>
  <ItemID>1056</ItemID>
</CollectionAddItemResponse>
```

Output shows Success, but it's not inserting the data as expected.  I suspect the xml needs to be encoded in some way, but I'm not sure...

The C# example is below from Mozenda's Site:

```
string webServiceKey = C70E1F84-E12B-4e73-B199-2EE6D43AF44E; //Your Account WebServiceKey.
string collectionID = 1001; //The ID of the destination Collection.
string url = string.Format(
"https://api.mozenda.com/rest?WebServiceKey={0}&Service=Mozenda10&Operation=Collection.AddItem&CollectionID={1}",
webServiceKey, collectionID);
string fileName = "C:\\Temp\\NewItems.xml"; //Path to the file containing the items to be uploaded.

WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] responseBinary = client.UploadFile(url, fileName);
string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary);
```

Comment: I fixed fileName = '/Users/me/Desktop/test.xml' to be  fileName = '\Users\me/Desktop\test.xml' with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting up your request correctly. When you do a POST request, you have to set up the body of the request in the way specified by [RFC 1341, section 7.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Here is an example in Python

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits
from random import choice

# Open your data file
with open("C:\datafile.xml", "r") as data_file:
    data_file_string = data_file.read()

# The URL
url = 'https://api.mozenda.com/rest?WebServiceKey=[CANNOT-PROVIDE]&Service=Mozenda10&Operation=Collection.AddItem&CollectionID=1037'

# The boundary delimits where the file to be uploaded starts and where it ends.
boundary = "".join(choice(ascii_uppercase + digits) 
                   for x in range(20))
body_list = []
body_list.append("--" + boundary)
body_list.append("Content-Disposition: form-data;"
                 " name='file'; filename=''")
body_list.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
body_list.append("")
body_list.append(data_file_string)
body_list.append("--{0}--".format(boundary))
body_list.append("")
body="\r\n".join(body_list).encode("utf8")

content_type = ("multipart/form-data; boundary="
                "{0}").format(boundary)
headers = {"Content-Type": content_type,
           "Content-Length": str(len(body))} # Tells how big the content is

request = Request(url, body, headers)

result = urlopen(url=request).read()
```

Comment: This is definitely the problem.  Thx for your feedback.  When I run the script I get the following:    File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/chicago-data/mozenda.py", line 26, in <module>
    body="\r\n".join(body_list).encode("utf8")
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected string, file found

Comment: You need to make sure the contents of your file get read into a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!  I change body_list.append(data_file) to body_list.append(data_file_string) and the POST works as expected!

Comment: You're welcome. I fixed the code for future reference.